# When I add setState I get error message about unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React for a search API. I am currently trying to add a button for each result that will display more info. I am doing this by using setState. When I add that to the code it seems to break my onClick function. With this code I get an error message saying unexpected token, pointing towards the onClick function.

```
let searchTerm;

class SearchBox extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        this.state = { repositories: [],
        showInfo: false };

    }


    render() {
    let moreDetail;
    if(this.state.showInfo){
    moreDetail= <div className="info">                    <li>
                    <p>Open issue count </p>:{item.open_issues_count}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <p>Number of forks </p>:{item.forks}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <p>Language </p>:{item.language}
                    </li></div>;
    }
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                <input type="text" className="searchbox"  ref={(input) => { this.searchBox = input; }}/>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Search</button>
                </form>
                <h2>Repositories</h2>
                <ul>
                { this.state.repositories.map( ( item, index ) => (
                <div key={ index }>
                  <a href={item.html_url}>  <li >
                        { item.name }

                    </li>
                    </a>


                    <button onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}>Detailed view</button>
                </div>
                )) }
                </ul>
            </div>
            );
    }

    _handleClick(){
    this.setState({
    showInfo: !this.state.showInfo
    });
    }
    }

    onClick(event) {

        searchTerm = this.searchBox.value;
        let endpoint = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=' + searchTerm;
        console.log(searchTerm);
        fetch(endpoint)
            .then(blob => blob.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ repositories: response.items });
            });
        event.preventDefault();

    }
}
```

I would appreciate help with sorting the button out or just fixing the error :) Thanks.

Comment: You have one too many closing curly braces. Try removing the extra one and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you paste your error message. Don't see any error here :/

Comment: thanks, yeah one to many curly brackets.

Comment: As you can see I'm using item.x in the {moreDetail} but it's not defined since I'm not mapping through it until later. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Could you make the code less readable by shifting a bit more the indentation... just kidding :) I'm not sure what your issue is, but one thing I can notice is that a map function definitely needs to return a value, you are not returning the mapped jsx in: this.state.repositories.map( ( item, index ) => { return (<div> {item.name + " stuff ..." }</div>)})

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma I know, it bothers me too :P It's all been sorted now :) thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a curly bracket too many.

let searchTerm;

```
class SearchBox extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        this.state = { repositories: [],
        showInfo: false };

    }


    render() {
    let moreDetail;
    if(this.state.showInfo){
    moreDetail= <div className="info">                    <li>
                    <p>Open issue count </p>:{item.open_issues_count}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <p>Number of forks </p>:{item.forks}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <p>Language </p>:{item.language}
                    </li></div>;
    }
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                <input type="text" className="searchbox"  ref={(input) => { this.searchBox = input; }}/>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Search</button>
                </form>
                <h2>Repositories</h2>
                <ul>
                { this.state.repositories.map( ( item, index ) => (
                <div key={ index }>
                  <a href={item.html_url}>  <li >
                        { item.name }

                    </li>
                    </a>


                    <button onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}>Detailed view</button>
                </div>
                )) }
                </ul>
            </div>
            );
    }

    _handleClick(){
    this.setState({
    showInfo: !this.state.showInfo
    });

    }

    onClick(event) {

        searchTerm = this.searchBox.value;
        let endpoint = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=' + searchTerm;
        console.log(searchTerm);
        fetch(endpoint)
            .then(blob => blob.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ repositories: response.items });
            });
        event.preventDefault();

    }
}
```